# Kubernetes Deployment object environment variables not present in container

Tags: kubernetes, environment-variables

I am  currently learning Kubernetes, and i am facing a bit of a wall.
I try to pass environmentalvariables from my YAML file  definition
to my container. But the variables seem not to be present afterwards.
`kubectl exec <pod name>  -- printenv` gives me the list of environmental
variables. But the ones i defined in my YAML file is  not present.

I defined the environment variables in my deployment as shown  below:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-world-boot
  labels:
    app: hello-world-boot
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello-world-boot
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello-world-boot
  containers:
    - name: hello-world-boot
      image: lightmaze/hello-world-spring:latest
      env:
        - name: HELLO
          value: "Hello there"
        - name: WORLD
          value: "to the entire world"
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: "128Mi"
          cpu: "500m"
      ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
    selector:
    app: hello-world-boot
```

Hopefully someone can see where i failed in the YAML :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I correct the errors in your `Deployment` configuration so that it looks like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-world-boot
  labels:
    app: hello-world-boot
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello-world-boot
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello-world-boot
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: hello-world-boot
          image: lightmaze/hello-world-spring:latest
          env:
            - name: HELLO
              value: "Hello there"
            - name: WORLD
              value: "to the entire world"
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: "128Mi"
              cpu: "500m"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
```

And deploy it into my local `minikube` instance:

```
$ kubectl apply -f pod.yml
```

Then it seems to work as you intended:

```
$ kubectl exec -it hello-world-boot-7568c4d7b5-ltbbr -- printenv
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/bin
HOSTNAME=hello-world-boot-7568c4d7b5-ltbbr
TERM=xterm
HELLO=Hello there
WORLD=to the entire world
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP=tcp://10.96.0.1:443
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PROTO=tcp
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PORT=443
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_ADDR=10.96.0.1
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST=10.96.0.1
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT=443
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT_HTTPS=443
KUBERNETES_PORT=tcp://10.96.0.1:443
LANG=C.UTF-8
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk
JAVA_VERSION=8u212
JAVA_ALPINE_VERSION=8.212.04-r0
HOME=/home/spring
```

If you look at the above output, you can see both the `HELLO` and `WORLD` environment variables you defined in your `Deployment`.

Comment: Thank you Larsks. You pointing out that you had to correct the deployment configuration, made me wonder  why i did not recieve any errors on that, and it turns out that i had neglected to configure the script that was runing the entire deployment, and where creating the deployment with CLI  commands instead. Very silly mistake on my part...... Now  it is working,  thanks you larsks for pointing me on the right track! :D